# Which versions of Android support VPNs?

Tags: vpn

Which versions of the OS can be configured to connect to a VPN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VPN capabilities (PPTP, L2TP and IPSec) for Android were included from version 1.6 (Donut) onwards.